# Will QGIS run on the latest MacOSX Catalina?

Tags: qgis, macos

I'm a lecturer at the University if the Highlands and Islands. We want to buy a MacBook Pro in the department (School of Adventure Studies), primarily to run QGIS. however, it is likely to come with the new MacOS Catalina.

Will the latest release of QGIS run on MacOS Catalina. I tried to find that info on the QGIS website but couldn't find any specific references to the new Mac OSX.

Comment: QGIS runs better on Windows because there are fewer bug testers using Mac. But in general, a new computer will be capable of running QGIS.

Comment: QGIS will generally run on a lower quality computer than ArcGIS, so if you buy a computer that meets their minimum specifications it will almost certainly run QGIS.

Comment: If you're really asking if QGIS for Mac is 64bit clean and signed, I'm not sure on either front, unfortunately, but I imagine the QGIS maintainer for the Mac branch is aware of the fun new requirements for easily running programs under Catalina and is working towards that.

Comment: Thanks for your advice everyone. Yes, I'm wondering if QGIS for Mac is 64bit as MacOSX Catalina doesn't support 32bit applicaitons. I'll keep investigating!